# cocoapod 'did not pass validation' error

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have fixed a bunch of podspec creation errors. Here is the output from `pod lib lint`:

```
-> KTPhotosViewController (1.0.0)
    - WARN  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPDecayAnimationInternal.h:61:11: warning: absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'const CGFloat' (aka 'const double') but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value [-Wabsolute-value]
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPDecayAnimationInternal.h:61:11: note: use function 'std::abs' instead
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPDecayAnimationInternal.h:61:11: note: include the header <cmath> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'std::abs'
    - WARN  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPSpringAnimationInternal.h:49:14: warning: absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'double' but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value [-Wabsolute-value]
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPSpringAnimationInternal.h:49:14: note: use function 'std::abs' instead
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPSpringAnimationInternal.h:49:14: note: include the header <cmath> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'std::abs'
    - WARN  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPSpringAnimationInternal.h:49:67: warning: absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'double' but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value [-Wabsolute-value]
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPSpringAnimationInternal.h:49:67: note: use function 'std::abs' instead
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  pop/pop/POPSpringAnimationInternal.h:49:67: note: include the header <cmath> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'std::abs'
    - WARN  |  IDMPhotoBrowser/Classes/IDMPhotoBrowser.m:298:26: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
    - NOTE  |  IDMPhotoBrowser/Classes/IDMPhotoBrowser.m:298:26: note: use function 'fabsf' instead
    - WARN  |  IDMPhotoBrowser/Classes/IDMPhotoBrowser.m:431:27: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  IDMPhotoBrowser/Classes/IDMPhotoBrowser.m:431:27: note: use function 'fabsf' instead
    - WARN  |  IDMPhotoBrowser/Classes/IDMPhotoBrowser.m:1256:42: warning: 'setCompletionHandler:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use completionWithItemsHandler instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    - NOTE  |  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIActivityViewController.h:19:69: note: property 'completionHandler' is declared deprecated here
    - NOTE  |  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIActivityViewController.h:19:69: note: 'setCompletionHandler:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  IDMPhotoBrowser/Classes/IDMPhotoBrowser.m:431:27: note: use function 'fabs' instead

Pods project available at `/var/folders/d7/_7pl6k7d7nz6k0vhw3d8tnqm0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj` for inspection.
```

My pod spec dependencies are:

```
s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'Foundation'
s.dependency 'Haneke'
s.dependency 'DACircularProgress'
s.dependency 'IDMPhotoBrowser'
s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
```

I am not sure how to resolve dependency warnings and force validation.

Comment: Please check this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link provided by Meet, all I had to do was validate using the `--allow-warnings` option.